# How do I change the distance between text and underline in TimePicker?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, timepicker

There is currently 12 pixels between the text and underline for timepicker and I want to set it to 7 pixels.

```
<materialDesign:TimePicker  SelectedTime="{Binding LabCase.AptTime}" />
```

In resource dictionary I have made these changes to style:

```
<Style TargetType="materialDesign:TimePicker" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type materialDesign:TimePicker}}">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
     <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="200" />
     <Setter Property="materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint" Value="" />
     <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-3,0,0" />
</Style>
```

Padding didn't work

```
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,7,0,0"/>
```

https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TimePicker.xaml

It seems like margin is the problem but I can't see to override it when I can override everything else

Comment: I think that you will have to override whole Template property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to override this whole control template:

```
<Style TargetType="materialDesign:TimePicker" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type materialDesign:TimePicker}}">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
     <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="200" />
     <Setter Property="materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint" Value="" />
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type wpf:TimePicker}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <Grid>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"                                             
                                              />
                                <wpf:SmartHint x:Name="Hint"
                                               FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                               UseFloating="{Binding Path=(wpf:HintAssist.IsFloating), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                               Hint="{Binding Path=(wpf:HintAssist.Hint), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                               HintProxy="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={x:Static converters:HintProxyFabricConverter.Instance}}"
                                               HintOpacity="{Binding Path=(wpf:HintAssist.HintOpacity), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition SourceName="Hint" Property="IsContentNullOrEmpty" Value="False" />
                                        <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True" />
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Hint" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="Hint" Property="HintOpacity" Value="1" />
                                </MultiTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="DropDownButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="Pressed"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <Viewbox>
                                    <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                                        <Path Data="M12,20A8,8 0 0,0 20,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,4A8,8 0 0,0 4,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,20M12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22C6.47,22 2,17.5 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2M12.5,7V12.25L17,14.92L16.25,16.15L11,13V7H12.5Z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                                    </Canvas>
                                </Viewbox>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                x:Name="border"
                                Padding="0 4 0 4"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                           
                                <TextBox BorderThickness="0" x:Name="PART_TextBox"                                                                               
                                         wpf:TextFieldAssist.TextBoxViewMargin=".5 0 0 0"
                                         Margin="0"                                     
                                         Template="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}"                                     
                                         />
                                <Button Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="4 0 0 -3" Grid.Row="0" Padding="0"
                                        x:Name="PART_Button"                            
                                        Height="17">
                                        Template="{StaticResource DropDownButtonTemplate}" />
                                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" 
                                       Placement="Custom"
                                       CustomPopupPlacementCallback="{x:Static wpf:CustomPopupPlacementCallbackHelper.LargePopupCallback}"
                                       PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}" StaysOpen="False"
                                       PopupAnimation="Fade"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <wpf:Underline x:Name="Underline" Visibility="{Binding Path=(wpf:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="TemplateRoot" Value="0.56"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsActive" TargetName="Underline" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ValidationErrorBrush}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Underline" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ValidationErrorBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>                        
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Inside the template you should ovveride Button with name x:Name="PART_Button"  ( for exmaple Height="17" ) or TextBox nearest to the button or x:Name="border"padding property.

Comment: This would be the proper way but you have a couple of mistake in it.

Comment: Hi this is original template from material design sources.

Comment: an extra > and one other thing. I forget. I posted my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Add height in you app.xaml and verify it. It worked for me. You can increase or decrease height to set text at your desired position.

```
      <Style TargetType="materialDesign:TimePicker" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type materialDesign:TimePicker}}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="200" />
            <Setter Property="materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint" Value="" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-3,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
        </Style>
```

Comment: This does change it but isn't consistent with mutiple time pickers. I'll upvote it as it might help someone later but it's not the best answer

Comment: It working fine in Multiple TimePicker as well. I have taken four TimePicker all in different rows, and space is similar in all four. Let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Didn't work correctly as it hid the bottom of the text on one and not the other so would work for identical ones but not slightly different ones.

Comment: For Identical you have to use the following in app.xaml file, and it will apply to all TimePicker. But make sure you don't apply height in at page level when  declaring control. **<Style TargetType="materialDesign:TimePicker" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type materialDesign:TimePicker}}">** For different one you can create key in app.xaml and use **<Style x:Key="TimePickerSetting" TargetType="materialDesign:TimePicker"/>** At page level(.xaml) **<materialDesign:TimePicker SelectedTime="{Binding LabCase.AptTime}" Style="{StaticResource TimePickerSetting}" />**

Answer (score 0):

Finished answer =

```
<Style x:Key="TimePicker" TargetType="{x:Type materialDesign:TimePicker}">     
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type materialDesign:TimePicker}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
                            <materialDesign:SmartHint x:Name="Hint"
                                           FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                           UseFloating="{Binding Path=(materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                           Hint="{Binding Path=(materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                           HintProxy="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={x:Static converters:HintProxyFabricConverter.Instance}}"
                                           HintOpacity="{Binding Path=(materialDesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition SourceName="Hint" Property="IsContentNullOrEmpty" Value="False" />
                                    <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="Hint" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Hint" Property="HintOpacity" Value="1" />
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DropDownButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="Pressed"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Viewbox>
                                <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                                    <Path Data="M12,20A8,8 0 0,0 20,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,4A8,8 0 0,0 4,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,20M12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22C6.47,22 2,17.5 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2M12.5,7V12.25L17,14.92L16.25,16.15L11,13V7H12.5Z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                                </Canvas>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            Padding="0"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox BorderThickness="0" x:Name="PART_TextBox"                                                                               
                                     materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.TextBoxViewMargin=".5 0 0 0"
                                     Margin="0"                                     
                                     Template="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}"                                     
                                     />
                            <Button Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="4 0 0 -3" Grid.Row="0" Padding="0"
                                    x:Name="PART_Button"                            
                                    Height="17"
                                    Template="{StaticResource DropDownButtonTemplate}" />
                            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" 
                                   Placement="Custom"
                                   CustomPopupPlacementCallback="{x:Static materialDesign:CustomPopupPlacementCallbackHelper.LargePopupCallback}"
                                   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}" StaysOpen="False"
                                   PopupAnimation="Fade"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <materialDesign:Underline x:Name="Underline" Visibility="{Binding Path=(materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="TemplateRoot" Value="0.56"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsActive" TargetName="Underline" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ValidationErrorBrush}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Underline" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ValidationErrorBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```